# amazon lex slot type with multiple values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

Could anyone help me to resolve the issue with amazon lex slot type.
Here is the requirement: I am using AMAZON.Organization slot type but it is not recognizing multiple words ( Lets say "Edge Connections")

Any help is much appreciated.
[Sample Utterances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VMyI.png)
[TestCase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21BpB.png)

Thanks,
Vempati

Comment: Please show how you have your bot set up. Either include the relevant part of your exported Lex JSON, or add some screenshots to the question. The slots section and the intent utterances are key. The more information you include in your questions the better, like an example ideal interaction compared to what you are getting. If there are no problems there, then I have a workaround to suggest, but let's start with making sure that the bot is set up correctly.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks for the quick response. Here is the snapshot attached.

Comment: Great, looks good. Now are you actually using the "Lambda initialization and validation" yet? Also just checking if you really want to use `AMAZON.Organization` which looks for "Names of non-governmental organizations" such as "tacobell", "amazon", "microsoft"? Because it looks like you want more specific and possibly less well known company names.

Comment: No I am not using Lambda initialization and validation, Is it needed?I have tried with custom type slot with the possible values and trained with data set ( 50 Values).Still it is not recognizing. I found only AMAZON.Organization, which is relevant to this use case by referring the documentation it can accept multiple words in the slots( eg: Edge Communication). Please suggest a better approach

Comment: The Lambda function will certainly be needed for more complicated interactions. The good thing about it though is that you can grab the exact user input whether or not Lex fills the slot, and you can fill it manually. But that really shouldn't be necessary yet. If all you are trying to do at this point is get the bot to recognize the two word input, not part of a preset list, then a custom slot type is the correct way. The values you set in slotType can be single words, phrases, or full sentences, so a proper set up should have no problem recognizing. You can include that set up in the Q.

Comment: Thanks for inputs, found the actual Issue. Lex is filling the slot , my fulfillment lambda is failing due to some validations.Issue is resolved.

Comment: @VSubrahmanyam how you solved this issue??

Answer (score 1):

1. Create **custom slot type** and define all the possible *account names* in it.
2. If you want your slot to accept only the values which you have defined then select **Restrict to Slot values and Synonyms** under Slot Resolution.
3. Then assign your custom slot type to the slot {AccountName}.

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon.Movie and set up a dialog code hook and store the value from the intentRequest.inputTranscript to the slot that you want to.

This is not a proper solution but coulr be used as a work around.

Thanks.